# How to connect to MySQL on local Docker development on AMI Linux with PHP7.1 using Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, lamp, amazon-ami

I've been working on a local Docker development environment now for about a week. We prefer to use Amazon Linux over Ubuntu or CentOS and RedHat.

Here are my steps I have taken to date:

1) Create a virtual machine to work from

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

2) Connect my terminal to that running virtual machine:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

3) Pull AMI Linux:

```
docker pull amazonlinux
```

4) Build a Dockerfile image container that has PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4

/AppFolder/docker/images/apachephp/ami/Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux
MAINTAINER Cameron Macfarlane <cammac1984@gmail.com>

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install httpd24 vim php71 php71-pdo php71-mbstring php71-pecl-imagick php71-opcache -y

EXPOSE 80

# Start the service
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"
```

5) Compile that up as killacam/apachephp

```
docker build -t killacam/apachephp docker/images/apachephp/ami/.
```

6) Create a vhost file to connect my local app to the doc root

/docker/vhost.cnf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ServerName docker.dev
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

7) Build a MySQL 5.6 Dockerfile (that chowns that /var/lib/mysql and exposes port 3306)

/AppFolder/docker/images/mysql/ami/Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux
MAINTAINER Cameron Macfarlane <cammac1984@gmail.com>

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install mysql56-server -y

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

EXPOSE 3306
```

8) Compile that up as killacam/mysql

```
docker build -t killacam/mysql docker/images/mysql/ami/.
```

9) Create a my.cnf file for MySQL configuration (user=root is the change)

currently it sits in AppFolder/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
user=root
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

character-set-server=utf8

10) Create a docker-compose file (version 2)

/AppFolder/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    apachephp:
        image: killacam/apachephp
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
        - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf
    networks: 
        - appnet
    mysql:    
        image: killacam/mysql #mysql:5.6 
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./data/:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
        tty: true
        networks: 
            - appnet
        #environment:
            #- "MYSQL_DATABASE=csg"
            #- "MYSQL_USER=test"
            #- "MYSQL_PASSWORD=qwe123"
            #- "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
networks: 
    appnet:
        driver: "bridge"
```

Run the file `docker-compose up`

When I pull open docker.dev:8080 in the browser I get DB connection issues. So far I have tried both the official MySQL 5.6 package and my own custom one.

I have also tried running just the `killacam/mysql` package by itself like so:

`docker run -it -p 3306:3306 -v $(pwd)/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf killacam/mysql;`

and starting up MySql with: `mysqld` but I keep getting this error

`[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist`

According to AWS AMI instructions found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html you need to run

`sudo service mysqld start` followed by `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

but when you try to run those command they fail with: `sudo service mysqld start` because the AMI docker image does not come with init scripts for some reason.

Anyone out there ever setup Docker to run MySQL on AMI for local development that can help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after posting this question I decided to give the official MySQL package another shot and now I am in business!

I had to add `user: "1000:50"` to my docker-compose file to get around some permissions issues, and I ended up removing the `MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD and MYSQL_DATABASE`, leaving only `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

For anyone who find them self with similar issue here is my final docker-compose.yml

`version: '2'
services:
    apachephp:
        image: killacam/apachephp
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./docker/vhost.conf:/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf
        networks: 
            - appnet
    mysql:

        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./data/:/var/lib/mysql
        user: "1000:50"
        tty: true
        networks: 
            - appnet
        environment:
            #  - "MYSQL_DATABASE=csg"
            #- "MYSQL_USER=test"
            #- "MYSQL_PASSWORD=qwe123"
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
networks: 
    appnet:
        driver: "bridge"`

and in my database configuration I needed to change the host to `DB_HOST=mysql`